# Amazon web services AWS: how to host java app, assign custom domain, custom domain name doesn't work properly

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, deployment, subdomain, web-deployment

I have a site hosted here: http://testapp-test.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/someservlet.do

The site contains an `index.jsp` and a `someservlet`.

In https://my.freenom.com cabinet I tried: to set nameservers and to set url forwarding to http://testapp-test.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com. 
The former doesn't work: I set the nameservers as the screen shows and when trying to access codingrecords.tk it is just blank. 
URL forwarding however works, and it does display the main page, but when I try to access http://codingrecords.tk/someservlet.do it still displays the `index.jsp` message.

How do I fix it? By specifying nameservers, rather than url forwarding? But then it doesn't work too..

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know how Elastic Beanstalk sets things up, but the normal way is to set up a Route53 DNS record for the domain you want to serve, and then use the Route53 nameservers in your DNS configuration at your registrar.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden That's what I tried to do. The first screen is me setting nameservers in registrar cabinet, the second screen in Route53 with those nameservers which I copied from there.

Comment: I guess, you need to set the alias to "No", If you select "Yes". Do you see the elastic bean stack app in the drop down?

Comment: @Sudharsan Sivasankaran, I noticed an error in the previous settings. I called a hosted zone `www.codingsrecords.tk` while it should be `www.codingrecords.tk`. I fixed that, created new hosted zone, added new nameservers to registrar and updated the screens. Do you mean alias of CNAME? I added the screen of a dropdown from there.

Comment: @Sudharsan Sivasankaran The problem is still there - this time the `codingrecords.tk` doesn't even load.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [sf]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so after lots of googling and trying out, I managed to make it work. I hope it will help future readers.

What I have done to deploy my java application in the custom domain in the Internet:

1. Get free domain in freenom.com
2. Create a key pair (don't know if it's necessary, just in case):
   2.1. Go to **Amazon Web Services - Services - EC2 - Key Pairs - Create Key Pair**

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

   2.2 Pick a some key_name for the key, save a file on your computer
3. Create an application and environment on AWS

   3.1 Go to **Amazon Web Services - Services - Elastic Beanstalk - Create New Application**

   [image]

   [image]

   3.2 Proceed to create new application, click next unless forced to fill something out; pick tomcat as a web server along the way; when come to a form where there's a **Key** label - pick an existing key with a name you assigned to it previously.

Pick a name - Next - **Create Web Server** - Select platform Tomcat - Next - Upload you .war file - Next - if you don't need a DB, click Next - set EC2 key pair to the key_name - Next - don't do anything with Environment Tags - Next - Next - **Launch**

3.3 Your application is lanched; you can see it at Elastic Beanstalk dashboard and you can see the running environment at **Services - EC2 - Instances**:

[image]

4. Create IP address:

   4.0 Go to **Services - EC2 - Instances**. Check the IPv4 Public IP column. If there's already an address there, go to point 5. If it's empty go to 4.1.

   4.1 Go to **Services - EC2 - Elastic IPs**:
   [image]

   4.2 Click **Allocate New Address**:

   [image]

   4.3 Pick it and click **Actions - Associate Address** - Select your app's instance - **Associate**:

   [image]
5. Set up **Route 53**:

   5.1 Go to **Services - Route 53**:
   [image]

   5.2 Go to **Hosted Zones**:

   [image]

   5.3 Click **Create Hosted Zone**:

   [image]

   5.4 Add your site's name to the form on the right (for instance, butterflies.com, somesite.edu, whatever):

   [image]

There appears a table with two record sets for your hosted zones: **NS** and **SOA** record sets.

5.5 Click on NS record set and copy paste nameservers from **Value** to your registrat's settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

5.6  Go to **Services - Elastic Beanstalk**, find your application - copy URL value:

[image]

Go back to Route 53, Click **Create Record Set**. Choose **Type**: A, **Alias**: yes, in the **Alias** target paste the URL. Click **Create**:

[image]

5.7 Click **Create Record Set**. Set name: www. Set type: CNAME. Set value to your_site_name.your_domain (for instance, butterflies.com), click **Create**:

[image]

6. It's done! Chances are, your_site_name is working.

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2019 and later: I recommend being very careful with AWS. My experience was that it's very easy to stumble into their paid services without even getting aware of it. They would easily charge you tens of dollars for some instance you have no idea is running. And finding and closing such instances is quite hard - at least for beginners like myself. I'm not even sure now if this answer is OK, since I ended up with using some of AWS services I didn't even need.

Comment: For Java I recommend using VPS like DigitalOcean and the likes - the price is lower, the usage is easier! DigitalOcean has free (gives you $100 upfront for two months) trial period and great guides - so even if you don't have Linux experience, it's pretty easy to set up a server and drop there your files. And they don't seem to try to lure and trap you with unnecessary services like AWS does - their user panel is very straightforward and obvious.

Answer (score 1):

So you only need 1 Public Route 53 zone for codingrecords.tk, then you can create a Route 53 resource record set for the sub domain www by creating an ALIAS record for the ELB given to you by Elastic Beanstalk.

Since you did create a route 53 zone for www.codingrecords.tk, I would delete that one(www.codingrecords.tk), Create a [Delegation Name set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/create-reusable-delegation-set.html) with the name servers below, use that name set when you create the Route 53 zone for codingrecords.tk. That way you don't need to change the NS records at the Registar.

```
dig @8.8.8.8 www.codingrecords.tk NS

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.codingrecords.tk NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38463
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.codingrecords.tk.      IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.codingrecords.tk.   21599   IN  NS  ns-1363.awsdns-42.org.
www.codingrecords.tk.   21599   IN  NS  ns-2005.awsdns-58.co.uk.
www.codingrecords.tk.   21599   IN  NS  ns-62.awsdns-07.com.
www.codingrecords.tk.   21599   IN  NS  ns-657.awsdns-18.net.

;; Query time: 134 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Feb 18 18:05:38 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 177
```

No name servers for codingrecords.tk

```
dig @8.8.8.8 NS codingrecords.tk

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 NS codingrecords.tk
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 55760
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;codingrecords.tk.      IN  NS

;; Query time: 156 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Feb 18 18:15:39 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 34
```

Answer (score 1):

Just changing Name in the last record to www.codingrecords.tk. should make it work. If it doesn't - then read below and see what else is wrong.

As this is elastic beanstalk, you should have an ELB configured for it. And all you need to do is add an A record for www.codingrecords.tk configured as an alias to your ELB.

And if you want http://codingrecords.tk to work as well, you need to add an A record for it as well (also aliased to either your ELB). But also see P.S. below. Not sure why it even worked for you - it's not present in your configuration above and it doesn't resolve when I try from my machine. Most likely you have it in your /etc/hosts or your local DNS, or something else to that effect.

I believe CNAME records should work too. But I never tried. To me, A type seems to be a slightly better choice in Route 53 as you can still configure it as an alias (thus ripping all the benefits of CNAME), but AWS will still return an actual IP address to a query, saving end user a round-trip in name resolution.

P.S. I also believe your NS and SOA records were meant to be for codingrecords.tk, not for www.codingrecords.tk. Whilst perfectly valid in your current configuration, they essentially saying that you own www.codingrecords.tk (and it's sub-domains), but not codingrecords.tk. I don't think this was your intention.